# What is the state of the art in Capital Growth Theory?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio-selection

I recently read [Online Portfolio Selection: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2129) by Li & Hoi. I rarely hear OPS talked about in the quantitative finance community, aside from different types of mean-variance optimization. So I have two questions:

1. Why is Online Portfolio Selection / Capital Growth Theory rarely discussed in quant finance? Is there some fundamental drawback or flaw in the theory?
2. What is the state of the art in OPS/CGT? What are the seminal papers?